# Getting values from a loop of asynchronous requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, deferred

I am trying to write a nodejs program that queries github for a list of repos (via a Node wrapper for the github API: https://www.npmjs.com/package/github) and retrieves the git clone url in an array, which I then wish to sort alphabetically.

Due to the asynchronous nature of the calls, I am not sure how to wait until all of the async requests are returned?

Here is the loop in question. `repoArray`is an array of repos in [username/reponame] format

```
var urls = [];

for (var i=0; i < repoArray.length; i++) {

    var components = repoArray[i].split('/');

    github.repos.get({
        user: components[0],
        repo: components[1]
    }, function(err, res) {
        urls.push(res.ssh_url);
    });
}

// do a case-insensitive sort
urls.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {'sensitivity': 'base'});
});

console.log("urls: " + urls);
```

Basically, since github.repos.get() calls in the loop are all asynchronous/callback-based, when the code reaches urls.sort() and then the console.log(), none or some of the github.repos.get() calls are done yet.

I am not that familiar with promises or deferreds, but is that the way to go? I'm not sure how I could refactor that loop so that urls.sort() is called only after **all** the requests from the loop are complete?

Answer (score 1):

The [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library is meant for exactly these scenarios, and is usually what people tend to use for these problems.  It can help you execute asynchronous tasks in parallel and execute a callback when they all finish, using [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback).

```
var async = require('async');
var urls = [];

//make each HTTP request
function process(repo,callback){    
  var components = repo.split('/');

  github.repos.get({
    user: components[0],
    repo: components[1]
  }, function(err, res) {
    if(err){
      // call callback(err) if there is an error
      return callback(err);
    }
    else{
      urls.push(res.ssh_url);
      // call callback(null) if it was a success,
      return callback(null);
    }
  });

}

// this will iterate over repoArray and pass each repo to the 'process' function.  
// if any of the calls to 'process' result in an error, 
// the final callback will be immediately called with an error object
async.each(repoArray,process,function(error){
  if(error){
    console.error('uh-oh: '+error)
    return;
  }
  else{
    // do a case-insensitive sort
    urls.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {'sensitivity': 'base'});
    });
    console.log("urls: " + urls);
  }
});
```

edit: since you are sorting them at the end, the urls will be in order.